# Swift - Alamofire - Parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I'm currently developing an app where I retrieve a JSON from a webservice using Alamofire.

The JSON Looks like this (http://258labs.be/others/getly-webservice/getuserslocations.php) :

```
    [
        {
            "first_name":"Ludo",
            "latitude":"50.8212662023034",
            "longitude":"4.36678815633465"
        },{
            "first_name":"Maxime",
            "latitude":"50.8214004366864",
            "longitude":"4.36678370989307"
        }
    ]
```

I've watched a lot of post on the internet parsing JSON in Swift, with or without Alamofire. And I never see a JSON without title who begin directly by a bunch of tuples. So I don't know how to how to parse it

Here's my Alamofire code :

```
// Get informations from others users

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://258labs.be/others/getly-webservice/getuserslocations.php").responseJSON() {
    (_, _, data, _) in
    println(data)

    for item in data! as [String: AnyObject] {
        println(item["first_name"])
    }
}
```

Could you point me the way to handle this JSON ?

Thanks in advance and Sorry If it's a repost, I tried to read most of the post and none looks like this.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Look at SwiftyJSON.  It pairs well with Alamofire

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Here is some code out of one of my test methods.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            var json = JSON(json!)
            println(json["flights"][0])

            expectation.fulfill()

    }
```

The `JSON(json)` call is parsing the data with SwiftyJSON

So in your case you would probably want something like:  `json["first_name"].string`

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an array of dictionaries.

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://258labs.be/others/getly-webservice/getuserslocations.php").responseJSON() {
    (_, _, data, _) in
    println(data)

    if let decoded = data as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
      for dic in decoded {
        println(dic["first_name"])
      }
    }

  }
```